# VC Dimension with rectangles with horizontal and vertical edges

Tags: machine-learning, theory

I am learning theory of machine learning and have some confusion about VC dimensions. According to the text book, the VC dimension of 2D axis-aligned rectangles is 4 which means it cannot shatter 5 points.

I found an example here: [Cornell](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs683/2008sp/lecture%20notes/683notes_0428.pdf)
[image: Sample]

However I still cannot understand this example. What if we use a rectangle like this (the red one)

[image: Another]

Then we can classify this point out of them. Why is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

We are supposed to draw the rectangle containing +ve examples only for any combination of the given 5 points. Here you see that, for any combination of the given points, a rectangle that corresponds to the points with maximum x-coordinate, minimum x-coordinate, maximum y-coordinate, and minimum y-coordinate will always contain the fifth point also. Hence, the set of 5 points cannot be shattered.